# Disable buttons behind image iOS

Tags: ios, image, button

I've working on an app and I built the interface visually and I have an image on the top that covers the entire view including the buttons underneath, the problem I am having is the buttons are still able to be clicked even whilst the image is covering them. Is this supposed to be happening, or am I missing something really simple?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of your image to `YES`, so that it will intercept all touches.

Comment: It already is enabled. This is what I originally thought but when I checked it I found it was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Disable button by using:
[button setEnabled:false];

You can also hide it i guess if you aren't using it 
[button setHidden:true];